# iOS: Layer shadow path is not correct

Tags: ios, uiview, shadow, quartz-core, cornerradius

I have `UIView` in my design and I need to allow user to change the corner radius. I have designed the testier using `@IBDesignable` and `@IBInspectable`.

I am getting the expected shape(`cornerRadius` curve) upto the 33% of `cornerRadius`

`e.g bounds.size.width = 100`,
 I am getting correct shadow shape if corner radius is upto 33.

If `cornerRadius` is more than 33 then shadow shape becomes circle irrespective of original shape `cornerRadius`.

Any suggestion?

Please refer the code and design screenshot below,

Code:

```
@IBDesignable class DrawingView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0.0

    @IBInspectable var borderWidth: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var borderColor: UIColor = .clear

    @IBInspectable var shadowRadius: CGFloat = 0.0
    @IBInspectable var shadowOffset: CGSize = .zero
    @IBInspectable var shadowColor: UIColor = .clear

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
        self.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
        self.clipsToBounds = true
        self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth
        self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.cgColor

        let path = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: self.bounds, cornerRadius: self.cornerRadius)
        self.layer.shadowPath = path.cgPath
        self.layer.shadowRadius = shadowRadius
        self.layer.shadowOffset = shadowOffset
        self.layer.shadowColor = shadowColor.cgColor
        self.layer.masksToBounds = false
        self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0
    }
}
```

**Screenshots**:

Corner Radius = 20%

[image: corenerRadius 20]

Corner Radius >= 33%

[image: cornerRadius >= 33]