# Wrong shadowPath for some cornerRadius

Tags: swift, uiview, shadow, cornerradius

Found that in some edge cases the shadowPath seems to render the shadow too rounded.

I'm applying the same shadow settings to all the subviews, I expected that the UIBezierPath with the same corner radius as the view, would behave the same. But seems that when the height starts to decrease they behave different.

Any idea why or how to fix it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: remove shadow path. `viewDidLayoutSubviews` is called when the view controller's view changes size, not when every subview changes size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like that

```
var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 32.0
let layerHalfHeight = subView.bounds.height / 2.0
if layerHalfHeight < cornerRadius {
    cornerRadius = layerHalfHeight
}

subView.layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: 0.0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: subView.bounds.width - cornerRadius, y: 0.0))
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: subView.bounds.width - cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 3.0 * .pi / 2.0, endAngle: 2 * .pi, clockwise: true)
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: subView.bounds.width, y: subView.bounds.height - cornerRadius))
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: subView.bounds.width - cornerRadius, y: subView.bounds.height - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: 0.0, endAngle: .pi / 2.0, clockwise: true)
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: subView.bounds.height))
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: subView.bounds.height - cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: .pi / 2.0, endAngle: .pi, clockwise: true)
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: cornerRadius))
path.addArc(withCenter: CGPoint(x: cornerRadius, y: cornerRadius), radius: cornerRadius, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: 3.0 * .pi / 2.0, clockwise: true)
path.close()
subView.layer.shadowPath = path.cgPath
```

So main idea is when the height of a layer become less then default corner radius * 2 then you need to change corner radius to half of the height.

Comment: Thanks for answering, that could fix the smaller view (1st at the top) but the problem I'm asking is mainly with the third.
The height of that view is 95px, so half is 47.5px, still bigger than 32px, so there's no change on the cornerRadius using your code.

I need a universal solution that works in all cases, for all heights and cornerRadius.

Comment: You are right seems there is an issue regarding UIBezierPath which calculate curve if corner radius is near half of width/height. I've updated my answer. Btw why do you use `path` at all? If you need only a shadow than you could just skip path setup. Set view `backgroundColor` instead to fill it.

Comment: I use the shadowPath as an optimization, is supposed to be more performant.
You solution works and looks perfect! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For now, I added a corrector for the UIBezierPath cornerRadius, it kind of works but feels like is not the proper solution.

```
    var cornerRadiusFix: CGFloat = cornerRadius
    if cornerRadiusFix > subView.bounds.height / 3 {
        cornerRadiusFix = cornerRadiusFix * 0.8
    }

    subView.layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: subView.bounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadiusFix).cgPath
```

Comment: Probably is related to this issue too..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53832090/ios-layer-shadow-path-is-not-correct

Answer (score 0):

For shadow path to work, you would have to change the bounds in `UIView.layoutSubviews` of the view with the shadow.

In your case, there is no need to use shadow path. Just remove the line setting the shadow path and everything will work correctly.

Comment: You're right, it will work, but performance will be worst. As specified in Apple documentation:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/calayer/1410771-shadowpath

Thanks anyways!

Comment: @pegpeg Uh, this is called premature optimization. Apple does not say that performance will be worst. Apple says that using an explicit path usually improves performance. They don't even specify how much. Anyway, there is nothing really wrong in your code, only the fact that you are not changing the shadow path when bounds change.